# Gradle: Could not get unknown property 'target'

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I added into my `build.gradle` the following task:

```
    task buildLambda(type: Copy) {
    from compileJava
    from processResources
    into('lib') {
        from configurations.runtime
    }
    into target
}

build.dependsOn buildLambda
```

Building the project in the Intellij IDEA produces the following Gradle error:

```
Could not get unknown property 'target' for task ':my- 
project:buildLambda' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.
```

But build finished successfully with Gordon framework. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`target` is not a known property that Gradle can interpret: you should write `into 'target'`  ( or: `into file('target')`  )